# How to inherit typescript types in a wrapper class

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

If I want to wrap httpClient in a wrapper class to provide extra features. How do i get the method return types directly from HttpClient. I do not want to recreate all these typing overloads for return types. By default I will lose all the typings information.

```
class myhttp{
    constructor(private _http:HttpClient){}
    get(url,options){
      return _http.get(url,options).pipe(this.customOperator())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this by extend httpclient class

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import {tap} from "rxjs/operators"


@Injectable({
  providedIn:"root"
})
export class HttpService extends HttpClient {
    
  public get(url , options?:any): Observable<any> {
    // do something magical ‍♂️
    return super.get(url,options).pipe(tap(console.log))
  }
}
```

inject `HttpService`

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private http:HttpService) { }
  
  ngOnInit(){
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe(console.log);
  }
```

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8hvucw)

Comment: you can remove the return type, since it will be inferred from `super.get`.

Comment: how about if I want to add extra param and attach rxjs custom operators

Comment: @FanCheung I have add options paramater , this just upper layer for httpclient so it work the same

Comment: I can achieve the same result without extend with just simply return http.get, in your httpservice.get try add super.get(url,options).pipe(tap(console.log)) see if the typing still remain or if it compiles

Comment: @FanCheung ether you extend httpclient or inject httpclient in the new service the result is the same

Comment: THanks for the effort but i don't think your solution is not working when I need to add custom pipable operators and also method overload

Comment: @FanCheung https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8hvucw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhttp.service.ts